# How to apply textchange as i typed in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

can anyone help me in formatting my textbox as i typed the digit or letter, im trying to type a TIME separated by a ":" as i typed.

```
    dim txtwk1monin as textbox
    Private Sub txtwk1monin_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtwk1monin.TextChanged
    Format(txtwk1monin.Text, "00:00")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered MaskedTextBox? See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx

Comment: i've never heard of that..but ill try to read that article, thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox.aspx) instead of a standard TextBox and set the [Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) property to `00:00`. To remove the underlines that are shown you can set the `PromptChar` property to `" "C`.

```
maskedTB.PromptChar = " "C
maskedTB.Mask = "00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also format the DateTimePicker to pick just time.  You can type and/or use scroll buttons